# Can somebody explain the resolution of the following limit?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-1}{|1-x|}$$

I checked at wolfram alpha and the result is $-1$, but i can't understand the resolution yet.

Comment: Why do you not understand? What is your reasoning and what do you think the solution is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $ x \leq 1 $, we have $ |1 - x| = 1 - x $. Therefore,
$$
  \lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{x - 1}{|1 - x|}
= \lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{x - 1}{1 - x}
= \lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{x}{- x}
= -1.
$$

---

**Additional Information**

I just realized that my original answer is unnecessarily complicated (as I typed it in a hurry). It can be simplified as follows.

For all $ x \leq 1 $, we have $ |1 - x| = 1 - x $. Hence,
$$
\forall x < 1: \quad
\frac{x - 1}{|1 - x|} = \frac{x - 1}{1 - x} = \frac{x - 1}{- (x - 1)} = -1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{x - 1}{|1 - x|} = \lim_{x \to - \infty} -1 = -1.
$$